# FFmpeg segmentation and inaccurate/wrong framerate

Tags: ffmpeg, frame-rate, segment

I use ffmpeg to save on files an RTSP stream at 15 fps. The command is similar to this (I've simplified it):

ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://IP/media.amp -c copy -r 15 -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_atclocktime 1 -strftime 1 outputFile%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4

It basically creates 1 minute long files from the stream, but the problem is that the framerate of every segmented file is NEVER 15fps.

The values that I get are something like this.

14.99874
15.00031

This is a huge problem for me because I need to merge these files with other 15fps videos and the result is not good. The merged file is unstable, the image crashes and sometimes even VLC crashes if I randomly click on the time bar.

If I just merge the stream files all is well, when I try it to mix it with something else, there is nothing I can do to have a video file that is watchable and stable.

Is this normal? What can I do to have segments with a fixed 15fps without re-encoding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save to TS. Duration of last frame in MP4 is getting truncated. Remux to MP4 if needed.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what's TS? Transport Stream file format? I've tried to remux to MP4 and it works but I have too much data to do it with the time constraints I have.
Thank you for your answer, it did open me some possibilities

Comment: TS = transport stream.  Remux should take seconds unless your files are large.

Comment: I saved to TS and it does the trick, but when I open a single TS file with VLC it displays no duration, what to do?

Comment: This is a VLC issue. ffprobe shows duration as does a player like Potplayer.

Comment: thanks, you have been very helpful

Comment: What are the commands I can use to fix this issue when my input is always an .mp4 file? In other words... how do I 'convert' it to TS? @Gyan

Answer (score 1):

As Mulvya pointed out, ffmpeg truncates the last frame.

There are two ways to solve this:

1) Save the files to another container other than mp4, it can be TS

2) Remove the last frame of the video also works but you have to use a filter which means re-encoding which can be long and heavy on the cpu/ram